# Kendo SaveAsExcel nan

Tags: excel, kendo-ui, export-to-excel, nan, kendospreadsheet

I'm generating a spreadsheet, where sometimes the data comes out as NaN.  Not a problem

However, when I "SaveAsExcel", and go to open the spreadsheet in Excel 2016 I get
"We found a problem with some content in 'reportname'.  Do you want us to try and recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click yes"
Clicking yes and I get that Excel was able to open the file with the following:

"Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part"

and a link to a log file which shows... Nothing

error072200_01.xmlErrors were detected in file MyFileName.xlsx'Repaired Records: Cell information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part

Now if I delete the NaNs on the sheet, I have NO issues.  Anyone have a clue how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you do it from a Kendo Grid?

Comment: Kendo Spreadsheet

Comment: Consider posting up some code, and a [reproducible example](http://dojo.telerik.com/) if possible.

Comment: What is `reportname` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated the problem and also suggested a solution - Go over all the cells of the sheet and check if the cell's value is `NaN` and validated as a number, if so, change the value to "".

You can change the solution to something that will fit your needs better of course.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
    <button id="export">Export to Excel</button>
    <div id="spreadsheet"></div>
    <script>
        $("#spreadsheet").kendoSpreadsheet({
            sheets: [{
                name: "Food Order",
                mergedCells: [
                    "A1:G1"
                ],
                rows: [{
                    height: 70,
                    cells: [{
                        value: "My Company", fontSize: 32, textAlign: "center"
                    }]
                }, {
                  cells: [{
                    value: NaN,
                    textAlign: "center",
                    validation: {
                      from: "1",
                      to: "2",
                      comparerType: "between",
                      dataType: "number",
                      messageTemplate: "Number should match the validation."
                    }
                  }]
                }],
            }],
           excelExport: function(e) {
               e.workbook.sheets[0].rows.forEach(function(row) {
                  row.cells.forEach(function(cell) {
                      if (isNaN(cell.value) && cell.validation && cell.validation.dataType === "number") {
                            cell.value = "";
                        }
                    });
                });
               console.log(e.workbook.sheets[0]);
            }
        });
        $("#export").click(function(e) {
            var spreadsheet = $("#spreadsheet").data("kendoSpreadsheet");
            spreadsheet.saveAsExcel();
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Load JSZIP library to enable Excel export -->
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.  Don't think the server should be producing an invalid excel file without it, but this did work

How do I mark as the answer

Comment: There's a check mark right below the down/up-vote counter

Comment: That is a good point, perhaps you should track down where the `NaN`s are coming from

Comment: I know where they are coming from.  I can have 3-6 "things" output.  The Blank ones obviously have some zeros in them, and I'm getting some Div/0s.  The "clean them out" is actually perfect, as I know if certain cells are NaN - I can kill entire columns of the sheet

Comment: Perhaps it will be better to prevent the NaNs from being written in the first place